# Where to find command line call to svcutil that is run from VS2015?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have WSDL that I'd like to import as a Service Reference.

The issue is that one of the service methods results in this error

> XmlSerializer attribute
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute is not valid in
>   Item. Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and
>   XmlAnyElement attributes are supported when IsWrapped is true.

I've seen posts that suggest using `svcutil /wrapped /serializer:XmlSerializer` might do the trick, but that seems to have issues with namespaces and not finding `any valid contracts or services, or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies.`

Since the Add Service Reference command from VS2015 uses svcutil, I'd like to see what options that uses, and modify that to add the /wrapped option.

Additionally, if I generate a Web Reference, that works, but I'm not happy with having to write a bunch of extra code to load the certificate used for the web service authentication. I'd rather use the web.config / app.config to define the bindings and end points.

Comment: You can try creating a console application that simply writes the received arguments, then replace `svcutil` with this application. Then you add the reference to the service from Visual Studio. Here the console application should start and print the parameters. Now you can restore the "real" `svcutil`

Comment: Good idea. I will give that a go on Monday.

Comment: Unfortunately, SvcUtil does not appear to get called when generating a Service Reference in VC2015. When keeping an eye on the process listing when generating a Service Reference, nothing external seems to get called.